# HTML input fields placeholder in IE

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

I have used a jquery ([**From this source**](http://bavotasan.com/2011/html5-placeholder-jquery-fix/)) solution to make placeholder to show in IE but for some reason it is not working for hidden fields in  my page.

If you look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/45/) here you can click on Add person button once u enter the adress and zip details, by clicking on Add person you can create some text fields.

And the problem is placeholder is not showing for those newly generated fields. Also wht the validation message of zip is displayed by default.

```
$(function() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    if(('placeholder' in input)==false) { 
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
            var i = $(this);
            if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
                i.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
                if(i.hasClass('password')) {
                    i.removeClass('password');
                    this.type='password';
                }           
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            var i = $(this);    
            if(i.val() == '' || i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {
                if(this.type=='password') {
                    i.addClass('password');
                    this.type='text';
                }
                i.addClass('placeholder').val(i.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                var i = $(this);
                if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
                    i.val('');
            })
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/49/) of your code:

```
$('.test').on('click', function () {
        if(!$("#signupForm").valid()){
            return;
        }            
        if (c<5){
            $('#loops').append( HTMLloop(++c) );
            setPlaceholder()
        }            
    });
```

needed to call placeholder functionality after creating new fields

this is a coll placeholder [plugin](https://github.com/andrewrjones/jquery-placeholder-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery code is configuring events only for elements that exist at the time that the code is run. Elements created afterward will not have those events attached to them.

In order to have a dynamic event that works with new elements that are created after the event is setup, you need to use the jQuery `$.on()` method rather than the `$().focus()` or `$().blur()` methods.

You should replace your existing event handlers like so:

```
$('[placeholder]').on("focus", function(){ .... });
```

this will make your placeholder events react to dynamically created elements.

Alternatively, you might consider trying out one of the other placeholder polyfill scripts that are available -- there are quite a few of them. [See here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder) for a few links.

Comment: http://diy.github.io/jquery-placeholder/ this is quite good from the site you referred but it is not applying for the generated input fileds. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/51/

Comment: Thanks for providing that link

Comment: @Sowmya - no worries. Note that the same page also has links to a ton of other polyfill scripts for other browser features that may be missing in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

See

```
.test{
display:inline-block;
background:red}
```

For message of zip